# Are bootstrap examples valid HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On the [bootstrap CSS guide](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), there are numerous examples like this:

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
```

Is it just me or is that `input` tag not closed? It's definitely not a typo - they seemingly never close input tags. What would be the reason to consistently do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5)

Comment: I'd recommend to self-close void elements, though, as XML compatibility is so easy to achieve that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `input` tag is what is called a *void element*, and *void elements* do not require an end tag.

Here is a complete list of all *void elements* within **HTML**:

- `area`
- `base`
- `br`
- `col`
- `command`
- `embed`
- `hr`
- `img`
- `input`
- `keygen`
- `link meta`
- `param`
- `source`
- `track`
- `wbr`

More about information *void elements* can be found here: **[Void Elements in HTML](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201005/void_empty_elements_and_self-closing_start_tags_in_html/)**

Comment: They don't allow an end tag.

Answer (score 2):

The `<input>` element is defined as being a void element. The end tag for void elements is forbidden.

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element):

> **Tag omission in text/html:** No end tag

Comment: OP didn't ask about end tags, he asked about *unclosed* input tags.

Comment: @connexo — End tags are how you close elements.

Comment: On void elements you use self-closing syntax. I wouldn't exactly call that *end tag*.

Comment: @connexo — Self-closing syntax is an XML feature. It isn't part of HTML.

Comment: I don't see OP's question being tagged HTML 5, but even if they did, they still didn't ask about end tags. They were obviously talking about self-closing syntax which is not mandatory, but perfectly valid HTML 5.

Comment: @connexo — "They were obviously" — No. It is not obvious that that is what they meant.

Comment: Why would anyone consider invalid `<input></input>` here? I disagree on your interpretation. Being a guy that comes from XHTML I strongly dislike HTML5 allowing for unclosed tags. Well-formedness is non-damaging, easy to achieve, and allows for validation by XML parsers.

Comment: @connexo — I disagree with pretty much everything in your last comment, but this really is not the right place to have a discussion about the merits and flaws of XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

According to w3schools.com, in **HTML** you do not need to close input tags at all.
But, in **XHTML**, the `<input>` tag must be properly closed, like this `<input/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually,  is a void element which means it's goal is not to contain text or whatever and it has a start tag but you shouldn't add an end tag.

This would not be W3C valid.
On the other end, non-void elements MUST have an end tag.

(List of void elements :
area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr)

Answer (score -1):

The input tag doesn't need a closed tag.

Just in xHTML the tag must be closed properly: `<input />`